# extract text from image and show it in html page

Tags: node.js, angular, image, ocr, extract

i have a problem  : i made a function to extract text from image with ocr space  api  in backend when i called  it with postTypeRequest(...) in angular  it worked
i added a declaration  text: string and i gave it the extracted text from backend to call it in html tag and show results in my project but it shows this problem : Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string'
the console shows an empty data like this :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmRDn.png
ress is empty and its type is object
so i think ress should return string not object

**home.component.ts**

`onSubmit() {`

```
    console.log('image', this.image);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.image ,'file');
    return   this.api.postTypeRequest('/api/scan/images', formData).subscribe((res) => {

       console.log(res) ;
       this.text =res //add a variable to call it in html {{text}} and show results

      }  )
```

`}`
**scan.controller.js**

```
const uploadImage =  (req,res)=> {
     
    let imageDetails = {
    name: req.file.originalname,
    };
  
    Scan.find({ name: imageDetails.name }, (err, callback) => {
    
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          err: err,
          message: `There was a problem creating the image because: ${err.message}`,
        });
      } else {
        let attempt = {
      name: req.file.originalname,
        imageUrl: req.file.path,
          imageId: "",
        };
        cloudinary.uploads(attempt.imageUrl).then((result) => {
          let imageDetails = {
          name: req.file.originalname,
            imageUrl: result.url,
            imageId: result.id,
        
           
          };
         
          Scan
            .create(imageDetails)
           
           
            .then((image) =>  {
            
              imageFilePath =imageDetails.imageUrl
          
              const rlt =   ScanService.createScan(imageFilePath).then( ()=>{
             
                 res.json({
                success: true,
                data: image,
                ress : rlt
              });
              })
               
     
     
             
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              res.json({
                success: false,
                message: `Error creating image in the database: ${error.message}`,
              });
            });
        
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

**scan.service.js**

````
const createScan = async (imageFilePath) => {
 
    ocrSpaceApi.parseImageFromUrl(imageFilePath, options)
   
    .then(function (parsedResult) {
      
        console.log('parsedText: \n', parsedResult.parsedText);
        console.log('ocrParsedResult: \n', parsedResult.ocrParsedResult);
        
       return  parsedResult.parsedText,parsedResult.ocrParsedResult
        
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('ERROR:', err);
      })}```
````

Comment: please post the code as a text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

The error is ocorring because you have an Object on the JSON response, so you need to check before assign the String value to your text.

In this case i yould recomendo you using a type check to make sure you are receiving your data as you expect.

Something on the lines of

```
if(typeof res !== "string") {
   this.text = "";
   return;
}
this.text = res;
```

Comment: thanks for help! ,  it accepts  this.text=""  i don't  know  why the type  is object  and not string  any suggestions?